# How do I use this java API? (answers to the similar Q already posted DON'T work in this case)

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I've downloaded vecmath-1.5.2.jar, which is supposed to be the jar file for javax.vecmath.Vector2f, which I'm trying to use. I've put it in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Graph\src\lib'.  C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Graph\src contains 2 folders: 'graph' and 'lib'. the 'graph' folder contains the program which uses javax.vecmath.Vector2f. However NetBeans is complaining that package 'javax.vecmath does not exist'. Can anyone tell me how to fix this please?

```
package graph;  

import java.util.Vector;  
import javax.vecmath.Vector2f;  

/**  
 *  
 * @author User  
 */  
public class Spline2D extends BasicSpline{  
   private Vector<Vector2f> points;
```

C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Graph\src contains 2 folders: 'graph' and 'lib'.

Comment: There *should* be an `import` clause at the top of the original code which will point you toward the proper `Vector2f` implementation. What does it lead to?

Comment: Netbeans is not aware this jar is in its classpath, there is probably something more you have to do. Added netbeans tag because this is specific to the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer on a duplicate question: you have to set the classpath to the JAR file containing the class, not just the directory it's in. (apologies: I realise it wasn't clear from the question that i hadn't already done this).

Answer (score 1):

`javax.vecmath` is part of the Java3D API. You can read everything about it on the oracle page. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html

But the project seems to be retired. There is no Version for Java 6 or 7. If you want to download the newest 1.5.2 Version, you can do that on the link above.